# How to implement Math.pow() inside pyomo-ipopt optimization?

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo, ipopt

I'm trying to optimize a motor selection for a given task, i.e. swing up of a double pendulum, Seems that ipopt is not solving the problem because it doesn't recognize

I have tried to implement math.pow() but doing that

Code:

```
from math import pow

def _epsilon_max(M,n):
    return M.epsilon_max[n]* pow(M.ratio_motor[n],0.8) -1== 0   
m.epsilon_max_cons = Constraint(m.dofs,rule=_epsilon_max)
```

Output:

TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type 
  `ratio_motor[1]' to a float is disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as arguments to one of the Python built-in math module functions when defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions.

Instead of using the implemented `pow` function it works only for integers

Code:

```
def _epsilon_max(M,n):
    return M.epsilon_max[n]*(M.ratio_motor[n])**0.8 -1== 0   
m.epsilon_max_cons = Constraint(m.dofs,rule=_epsilon_max)
```

Output:

> Ipopt 3.12.11:  Error evaluating constraint 1011: can't evaluate
>   pow'(0,0.8).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a model evaluation error and not that you can't have a fractional exponent. You need to initialize `M.ratio_motor[n]` to something other than 0. The second implementation using the Pyomo-implemented pow function is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the output `can't evaluate pow'(0,0.8)` means that IPOPT is unable to compute the first derivative during the solution. Defining bounds and initializing that variable in the definition will resolve the issue:

```
M.ratio_motor=Var(N,bounds=(1e-20,None),initialize=1e-20)
```