# Error evaluating power in Pyomo modelling constraint

Tags: python, constraints, pyomo

when running my script for dynamic data reconciliation the following errors appear:

Error evaluating constraint 54: can't evaluate pow(-68.9833,-0.666667).
ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.

Here it is the relevant part of the code:

```
def _dQcdt(model,i): # differential constraint for heat balance on cold fluid side

p=[2473.00, 1.33, 2419.00, 772.65, 14318.66] # physical parameters
Ac=p[0]*p[1]/3600
a=(p[4]/6)*((model.Thin[i]-model.Tcout[i])*(model.Thout[i]-model.Tcin[i])*0.5*(model.Thin[i]-model.Tcout[i]+model.Thout[i]-model.Tcin[i]))**(-2/3)
b=model.Thin[i]-model.Tcout[i]
c=model.Thout[i]-model.Tcin[i]
d=model.Thin[i]-model.Tcout[i]+model.Thout[i]-model.Tcin[i]   
dqdt=-a*model.Tcindot[i]*(b*d+b*c)+a*model.Thindot[i]*(c*d+b*c)
return Ac*(model.Tcout[i]*model.dVcdt[i]-model.Tcin[i]*model.dVcdt[i]-model.Vc[i]*model.Tcindot[i])-dqdt==0 
model.Qccon=pyo.Constraint(model.time,rule=_dQcdt)
```

I bounded all the variables in order to be always positive and different from zero and I initialized them too. Nothing changed apart from the value of the power base. I also tried to create a new variable for the term 'a', bounding it in order to avoid negative power bases.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to take a close look at the variables and constraints in the expression that you are raising to the (-2/3) power.  The error is telling you that you are trying to raise a negative number to a fractional power, which is causing the error.  somehow the base of your value is -68.9...

Comment: @AirSquid, I'll have a close look again. As you pointed out the problem is raising a negative number to a fractional power, and I'm wondering how it is possible when I constrained the different variables and terms to be postive.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/77413740/4606005